# HttpContext to ObectContext Connection helper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, httpcontext, objectcontext

I had this below connection helper class in Visual Studio 2010

```cs
public class ConnectionHelper : IConnectionHelper
    {
        public ObjectContext Connection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connection == null && HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] != null)
                {
                    _connection = (ExampleWebsiteEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"];
                }
                else
                {
                    _connection = new ExampleWebsiteEntities(ConnectionString);
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] = _connection;
                }
                return _connection;
            }
        }
        private ObjectContext _connection;

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExampleWebsiteEntities"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

This above class works fine in Visual Studio 2010 but giving two errors in Visual Studio 2012

**1- Cannot implicitly convert type 'Example.Datalayer.ExampleWebsiteEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'**

on this line code

```cs
_connection = (ExampleWebsiteEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"];
```

**2- 'Example.Datalayer.ExampleWebsiteEntities' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

on this line code

```cs
_connection = new ExampleWebsiteEntities(ConnectionString);
```

I have double checked everything, but can't figure out what is the issue. 
Please help me in this. Thank you very much and Regards

Comment: how ExampleWebsiteEntities looks like?

Comment: @VladimirShmidt: a category table, and image table. each category have 5 images stored in image table. query category table and get images from image table using category Id.